# Access remoteEntry from Module Federation in a content script

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, content-script, webpack-module-federation

**TL;DR** - Can I access Module Federation remotes from within a content script of a chrome extension?

I'm currently developing a Chrome extension and faced the problem that can be represented by the following.
Let's say I have 2 applications - **extension** and **actionsLogger**.
These applications are linked via Webpack Module Federation like that:
**actionsLogger/webpack.js**

```js
{
  ...,

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'actionsLogger',
      library: { type: 'var', name: 'actionsLogger' },
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './logClick': './actions/logClick',
      }
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization'
    },
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    }
  },

  ...
}
```

**extension/webpack.js**

```js
{
  ...,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      browser: 'webextension-polyfill'
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'extension',
      remotes: {
        actionsLogger: 'actionsLogger@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js',
      },
    }),
  ],
  ...
}
```

So, as you can see, **actionsLogger** is running on port 3000 and **extension** is referring to it via Module Federation. **actionsLogger** contains a simple function to get position of a cursor in case of a click event.

**actionsLogger/actions/logClick.js**

```js
function logClick(event) {
  return { X: event.clientX, Y: event.clientY };
}

export default logClick;
```

Other application - **extension**, contains all the code for the chrome extension together with this particular script that imports `logClick` from **actionsLogger/logClick** and sends the position of a cursor to the background page whenever a click happens:

**extension/tracker.js**

```js
import('actionsLogger/logClick').then((module) => {
  const logClick = module.default;
  
  document.addEventListener("click", (event) => { 
    const click = logClick(event);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(click);
  });
});
```

So `manifest.json` in **extension** looks like this:

**extension/manifest.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["tracker.js"]
  }],
  ...
}
```

And here comes the problem. If I try to open some web page with the **extension** installed and running, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js)
while loading "./logClick" from webpack/container/reference/actionsLogger
    at webpack/container/reference/actionsLogger (remoteEntry.js":1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:18:1)
    at handleFunction (remotes loading:33:1)
    at remotes loading:52:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.f.remotes (remotes loading:15:1)
    at ensure chunk:6:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (ensure chunk:5:1)
    at iframe.js:44:1
```

First of all, I thought that I misconfigured something in my Module Federation settings, but then I tried the following - added **inject.js**:

**extension/inject.js**

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "chrome-extension://ddgdsaidlksalmcgmphhechlkdlfocmd/tracker.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Modified **manifest.json** in **extension**:

**extension/manifest.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["inject.js"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "tracker.js",
  ]
  ...
}
```

And now Module Federation works fine, but since **extension/tracker.js** imports `import('actionsLogger/logClick')` from a remote, some websites that have content security policy defined might block this request (e.g. [IKEA](https://www.ikea.com/)). So this approach also won't always work.

And the initial problem with accessing MF module from content script probably happens because content scripts are running in their own isolated environment and module federation can't resolve there properly. But maybe there are some configuration flags/options or some other/better ways to make it work?

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Your code (both in the question and in the answer) is running inside the JS context of the page (MAIN world) because it uses DOM `script` elements, so the page or other extensions can trivially hack into your webpack loader and intercept/spoof all data via object prototypes. The proper solution is either to bundle all code in one file or use the native ES module import ([example](/a/53033388)) so that the code runs in the isolated world by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, minutes after I posted the question I came up with a working solution. So, basically, I decided to use the second approach where **extension/tracker.js** is injected via `<script />` tag on a page by **extension/inject.js** and for the CSP issue I've added a utility that blocks a CSP header on a request for the page.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "permissions": [
     ...,
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "browsingData",
    ...
  ]
}
```

**extension/disableCSP.js**

```js
function disableCSP() {
  chrome.browsingData.remove({}, { serviceWorkers: true }, function () {});

  const onHeaderFilter = { urls: ['*://*/*'], types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'] };

  browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    onHeadersReceived, onHeaderFilter, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
  );
};

function onHeadersReceived(details) {
  for (let i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++) {
    if (details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'content-security-policy') {
      details.responseHeaders[i].value = '';
    }
  }

  return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };
};

export default disableCSP;
```

And then just call `disableCSP()` on the background script.

I'm a bit unsure about security drawbacks of such an approach, so feel free to let me know if a potential high risk vulnerability is introduced by this solution.